# Cannot connect two ECS services via Service Discovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am new to AWS and I am trying to deploy simple app to AWS ECS. I have two simple docker containers, running in ECS Fargate:

- ‘Frontend’: Vue Js app, which makes a single request to backend;
- ‘Backend’: Django app, which serves the request;

Both services were launched within the same cluster, in default VPC and the same, single public subnet. For ‘Backend’ I configured Service Discovery: Namespace – **test**, Service Discovery Name – **backend**. Security group configured to allow All Traffic.

So, the problem is when frontend makes request:

```
axios.get('http://backend.test:8000/api/get-test/')
```

I got error: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED  backend.test:8000/api/get-test/`

However, executing in AWS Cloud9 command: `dig +short backend.test` returns correct private IP of the backend container.

When I change request to something like

```
axios.get('http://172.17.3.85:8000/api/get-test/')
```

where 172.17.3.85 is valid private IP of the backend container, I got following error:

`GET http://172.17.3.85:8000/api/get-test/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

However, if I spin out EC2 instance in the same VPC and subnet and SSH to it, I can ping backend container, and requests -

```
curl -v http://172.17.3.85:8000/api/get-test/
```

as well as

```
curl -v http://backend.test:8000/api/get-test/
```

return desired response.

The only case when everything is working as expected is when the request is like

`axios.get('http://3.18.59.133:8000/api/get-test/')`,

where 3.18.59.133 is valid Public IP of the backend container.

I would appreciate any suggestion where look further or how to connect two containers via service discovery as right now I am out of ideas.

Comment: Does your vpc have  dnshostnames and dnssupport enabled?

Comment: Yes, both DNS hostnames and DNS resolution in my VPC are enabled

Comment: Can you go to R53 and confirm the A or/and SRV entires are there? Also you used A or SRV or both? From my experience, SRV alone often causes issues.

Comment: I am using DNS Record Type A only. I am not 100% sure where to look for A/SRV entries in R53, but if I go to R53 -> Hosted Zones -> test, there is entry for 'backend.test', type A, private IP, etc.

Comment: A is fine. Have you used `dig` to check if your private hz resolves to the correct ips? `dig backend.test`?

Comment: Yes, as I mention in description, executing `dig +short backend.test` returns correct private IP

Comment: I see. What about security groups? If call 172.17.3.85 times out, maybe there is issue with SGs?

Comment: Security group is set to allow all traffic. I tried to change it to Custom TCP with port 8000, did not help. Besides, curl request to private IP and any request to public IP work just fine.

Comment: By any chance, the frontend executes `axios` on the client side? For example, from a browser? If this code runs on client side, it could explain why you get the errors. It will only resolved if called from withing a vpc, not in the browser outside of AWS or VPC.

Comment: Ok, now I see. Yeah, the request comes from a browser.  Thank you @Marcin

Comment: I just added more detailed answer. And no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments and description of the problem, the  reason is that the `Frontend’: Vue Js app` **executes on the client side**, for example, in the browser.

This explains all the issues described and discussed:

- `axios.get('http://backend.test:8000/api/get-test/')` **does not work** as on the client side you can't resolve privte hosted zone.
- `axios.get('http://172.17.3.85:8000/api/get-test/')` **does not work** because the `172.17.3.85` is valid only in the VPC, not on the client's network.
- `spin out EC2 instance in the same VPC and subnet and SSH` **works** because private hosted zones can be resolved inside VPC.
- `axios.get('http://3.18.59.133:8000/api/get-test/')` **works** because public IP can be used on the clinet side, unlike private IPs.

Comment: So what is the solution here? Doesn't Fargate all about NOT spinning out EC2 instances manually? How can I deploy both front and back apps on fargate without the need to manually create EC2 instances?