# ECS unable to send API requests to backend using service discovery

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, service-discovery

I deployed a front and back apps with ECS fargate, both of them are up and running and I can access them from my browser. They are configured on the same VPC and subnet.

The backend has service discovery configured and my server's DNS address was inserted to my react application.

I read in this thread [cannot-connect-two-ecs-services-via-service-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108706/cannot-connect-two-ecs-services-via-service-discovery) that if I use axios from my browser to access my server using service discovery it will not work.

The error I am getting is: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

How can I achieve communication between these 2 services with service discovery? Am I missing something?

Comment: is there any update on this issue? I am facing the same issue.